# How to Reset the fact-index when assert new fact?

Tags: clips

I have embedded CLIPS into C Language. 
I have situation like this:
in a .clp file, I have fact list

```
(deftemplate sensor
 (slot name) 
 (slot status)) 

(deffacts FRONTSENSOR
(sensor (name 1) (status 1))
(sensor (name 2) (status 1))
(sensor (name 3) (status 0))
(sensor (name 4) (status 0))
(sensor (name 5) (status 1))
(sensor (name 6) (status 0))
(sensor (name 7) (status 0))
(sensor (name 8) (status 0)))
```

now I want to cancel these facts and assert new facts in to the list.
I use `Retract(factPtr);` to cancel facts and use `AssertString("(sensor (name 1) (status 0))");` to assert fact.
And I print the fact list, result is

```
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-11    (sensor (name 1) (status 0))
f-12    (sensor (name 2) (status 0))
f-13    (sensor (name 3) (status 1))
f-14    (sensor (name 4) (status 0))
f-15    (sensor (name 5) (status 0))
f-16    (sensor (name 6) (status 0))
f-17    (sensor (name 7) (status 1))
f-18    (sensor (name 8) (status 1))
For a total of 9 facts.
```

the fact-index is start from 11 instead of 1, I wonder if there is function or solution that the new asserted fact can start from f-1.
Ps：`Clear()`function can reset the fact-index, but the rules will also be cleaned. It seems not helpful.

Thank for answers or any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reset() function will remove all the facts and reset the fact-indices without removing any of the rules.

Comment: Thanks, but if use Reset() function, the "deffacts FRONTSENSOR" will also assert to the list again.

Comment: Then no, there is no mechanism for resetting the fact index without doing a reset. The assignment of the index is a direct assignment to the fact and then increment of a next fact index value, so if you were to reset it to 0 without removing all existing facts you'd end up with multiple facts having the same index.